# Salesforce include different visualforce page based on condition

Tags: visualforce

I need to include different VF page based on a condition as below.

`<apex:include pageName="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.methodType=='CC' && $User.superUser__c  ,'SuperVFpage','NormalVFpage')}"/>`

in the above code `$CurrentPage.parameters.methodType=='CC'` is causing salesforce internal server error. Would you please help me what is wrong with above code?

Comment: Trying to reproduce this myself, the `$CurrentPage.parameters.methodType == 'CC'` bit seems to work just fine. How did you determine that this part of it was your issue? Are you sure that you're not getting a save error with `$User.superUser`? Do  you get the same error when you try to independently view either one of the two Visualforce pages you're trying to include?

Comment: I've never heard of the superUser field, is that a custom field or are you trying to user IsPrmSuperUser?

Comment: Sorry, I edited. Yes, it is a custom field.

Comment: It works fine if I replace $CurrentPage.parameters.methodType with 'anytext'